# How to Create a folder on the server with several username and password to download the file with particular time for each user

Tags: php

How to create a folder on the server with multiple user name and password to download the file with a specific time for each user, and only one user access to a folder on the server at one point and a user name and password do not have multiple connection

note:
The particular time for each user
Please code examples

Comment: what do you mean by user specified time?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by user specified time?

To download a file with username + password, you can use a PHP script which will check authentification, and if the user is logged in, do a simple readfile() (with appropriate headers)